# Add scroll to div inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have a div that scrolls which is contained within a flex element that's expanded to fill the page. Currently, it just overflows its container.

I've taken a look at questions such as: [Scrolling a flexbox with overflowing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content) with no luck

In my code, the blue content div which should scroll and be contained to the lightblue div overflows and spills over.

This is my current structure:

```css
.base {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
  /*   overflow: hidden; */
}

.instructions {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.header {
  background: teal;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='base'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='instructions'>
      <div class='header'>this is the header</div>
      <div class='content'>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's an example on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNryJZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

Kindly see code below, tested in IE 11 and Chrome.

```css
.base {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.instructions {
  background: red;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  background: teal;
}

.content {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class='base'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='instructions'>
      <div class='header'>this is the header</div>
      <div class='content'>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
        <p>This is content</p>
        <p>This is a lot of content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not in your original code as well, should add `display: -moz-flex;` for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

one more example

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
}
#header {
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
}
#right-col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#inner-right {
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="right-col">
      <div id="header-text">Header</div>
      <div id="inner-right">
        <p>
          Accesory 1
          <br>Accesory 2
          <br>Accesory 3
          <br>Accesory 4
          <br>Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8 Accesory 1
          <br>Accesory 2
          <br>Accesory 3
          <br>Accesory 4
          <br>Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8 Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```