# How to scroll display flex div to bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html

I can see traditionally you can set `scrollTop` of a div and scroll it to bottom like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jPVAf/50/

But if my div is `display: flex`, the above technique won't work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hoch47n6/. How do you use JS to scroll the div to bottom? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's not because of `display: flex` itself as of fact that you just can't scroll the div at all. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `justify-content` property.

And reset the properties of `<p>` and use `line-height` to let the jQuery take the actual height of the `<p>` tag

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoch47n6/2/)** (jsFiddle), have a look.

For reference,

```
/* Resetting <p> */
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Hope this helps!