# CSS for having a scrollable div, take up 100% available height, but not add scroll bar to body

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I'm trying to get a layout to work without any JS, just HTML and CSS.

```
top-div
left-div      center-div      right-div
```

The idea is to have vertical scroll bars on the center div, but nowhere else on the page, including the body.

It seemed like the best idea would be a vertical flexbox, to make the top row and bottom row, then a horizontal flexbox, to make left, center, and right.

How hard could that be?

Well, if you look at this fiddle, it's clearly too hard for me to make sense:

https://jsfiddle.net/gL4pwkxu/1/

The document always wants to stretch past the height of the window. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky to get working. From this SO post: [Scrolling a flexbox with overflowing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content), There's a need to add an element that creates its own height from the content. But I had to set the `full-page` height to `100vh` (View Height units) AND set the height of `content` to anything and then it worked. See below...

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

full-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 1px; // hackery
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

#right-column {
  background-color: blue;
}

#main-column {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto; // used 'auto' so it only appears if you need it
}

#main-column > div {
  min-height: min-content; // magic
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
  <full-page>  
    <header>top</header>
    <content>
      <nav>left</nav>
      <div id="main-column">
        <div>
          center<br>
          b<br>
          v<br>
          d<br>
          e<br>
          e<br>
          f<br>
          f<br>
          d<br>
          e<br>
          e<br>
          f<br>
          d<br>
          e<br>
          e<br>
          f<br>
          f<br>
          f<br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right-column">right</div>
    </content>
  </full-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I felt like with flexbox and grid, it should be amazingly simple and I was just thick. That still could be true. Thanks again. 1px makes all the diff

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are ignoring the height of the 
`<header>top</header>` element
I also changed the height units to viewport height instead of %. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/zL6y7x2j/

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd like the the header to be a specific height, not a percentage. I thought flex box would make it easy for the top row to be a specific height, and the bottom row to fill the rest of the screen, but no more.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the window scroll add:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, to make the div scrollable:

```
#main-column {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: static;
}
```

Comment: True, I can hide the body's scroll bar, but the since the center column still adds height to the document, things in the right column are now cut off: https://jsfiddle.net/deLkzhc1/