# Flexbox set overflow inside another flexbox with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on an electron app, this is what my layout looks like:
[image]

Heres my corresponding structure:

```js
max_elements = 20

function generate(e){
    html = ""
    for (i = 0; i < max_elements; i++){
    html += `<li>Element ${i + 1}</li>`
  }
    e.innerHTML = html
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#root {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#top {
  height: 50px;
}

#main {
  flex: 1;
}

#mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainWindow {
  flex: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.list {
  overflow: auto;
}

#bottom {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"> <!-- Imagine the root id as Electron App Window. -->
    <div id="app">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="top">HEADER</div>
        <div id="main">
          <div id="mainContainer">
            <div class="mainWindow">
              <div class="winHeader">WINDOW 1 HEADER</div>
              <div id="a" class="list" onclick="generate(a)">CLick Here for the list</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainWindow">
              <div class="winHeader">WINDOW 2 HEADER</div>
              <div id="b" class="list" onclick="generate(b)">CLick Here for the list</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">FOOTER</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My problem is, that no matter what I'm trying, the List is expanding and never overflows, pushing down the footer out of the window (and itself, too).

---

I've been searching for answers, but none of which I found fixed my problem. 
E.g. every answer in [Scrolling a flexbox with overflowing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content) does assume that theres a fixed height somewhere you can work with, which I don't have.

When resizing the window, ***only the main window should expand***, while the bottom and top should always stay where they are. You could also take a look at how Resizing in e.g. Filezilla works, which is exactly the behaviour I want.

---

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh5knsjb/71/

Comment: Do you need a scrollbar if overflow?

Comment: Yep (min character limit...)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jd8r3h4p/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good:

```js
max_elements = 20

function generate(e){
    html = ""
    for (i = 0; i < max_elements; i++){
    html += `<li>Element ${i + 1}</li>`
  }
    e.innerHTML = html
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#root {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#top {
  height: 50px;
}

#main {
  flex: 1;
  min-height:0; /* added */
}

#mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainWindow {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  /* added */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.list {
  overflow: auto;
}

#bottom {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"> <!-- Imagine the root id as Electron App Window. -->
    <div id="app">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="top">HEADER</div>
        <div id="main">
          <div id="mainContainer">
            <div class="mainWindow">
              <div class="winHeader">WINDOW 1 HEADER</div>
              <div id="a" class="list" onclick="generate(a)">CLick Here for the list</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainWindow">
              <div class="winHeader">WINDOW 2 HEADER</div>
              <div id="b" class="list" onclick="generate(b)">CLick Here for the list</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">FOOTER</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: After implenting this, it still didnt work. I found out the initial problem was that SASS (which I have used) didn't convert my CSS to what it should've, thus the CSS never did what it should have. After rewriting everything in pure CSS everything worked as expected!