# Material UI Scrollable Tabs inside Drawer content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui drawer based on the [mini variant drawer](https://v4.mui.com/components/drawers/#mini-variant-drawer). Inside the drawer content, I have a set of tabs based on the [prevent scroll buttons tabs](https://v4.mui.com/components/tabs/#prevent-scroll-buttons). I'm using material-ui version 4.12.3.

Unfortunately, the tabs inside the drawer expand beyond the width of the screen and add a horizontal scrollbar. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-and-scrollbar-ytxdi?file=/src/App.js) for the code and example. I would have expected the tabs to just fill the width of the drawer content and to become scrollable, like in the material-ui example.

Is there any way to make those tabs work as they do in the material-ui example linked above, while keeping the drawer functionality as it is?

Comment: One solution is you can add `width: "calc(100% - 73px)"` inside the `content` class in `MiniDrawer.js` to make it take only the available width of the screen. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-and-scrollbar-forked-0b2ug?file=/src/MiniDrawer.js:2603-2629)

Comment: It's because the scrollable container uses flexbox: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35609992/9449426

Comment: @NearHuscarl I added `overflow: hidden` to the parent container as explained in the answer you linked and it worked. Thanks! See the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-and-scrollbar-forked-jgmsg?file=/src/MiniDrawer.js:2603-2622)

Comment: @N.Jones You're welcome. That one took me a while, I was so stressed out while finding the solution that when I actually found it I don't have the energy left to write an answer and make a working demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer here that expands on NearHuscarl's comment to close this off.

Adding `overflowX: hidden` to the content div in my example fixed it. See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-and-scrollbar-forked-jgmsg?file=/src/MiniDrawer.js:2603-2622) for the updated code.

The issue was happening because the parent of the scrollable tabs needs to have `overflowX: hidden` in order for the horizontal scroll functionality to work. Otherwise the scrollable tabs just causes its parent's width to expand. More details on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35609992/7373512) linked by NearHuscarl